# Error when running in Docker The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.6' was not found. on

Tags: docker, .net-core

I try running a project with a GenericHost in docker. It works running the console app locally on my machine, and builds correctly. If I remove some code and the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App it works good, so the issue seems to be isolated to that package when running it on Docker.

Error message:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '2.1.6' was not 
found.
- Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
  /usr/share/dotnet/
- Installing .NET Core prerequisites might help resolve this problem:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
- The .NET Core framework and SDK can be installed from:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program '[24] dotnet' has exited with code 150 (0x96).
The program 'dotnet' has exited with code 150 (0x96).
```

Below is my DockerFile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ../TestProj/TestProj.csproj ../TestProj/
RUN dotnet restore ../TestProj/TestProj.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/../TestProj
RUN dotnet build TestProj.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish TestProj.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestProj.dll"]
```

The original Docker file includes some more "COPY" because of references needed, but edited those out here.

*update*
Local machine:

```
dotnet --info
.NET Core SDKs installed:
1.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
1.1.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program 
Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program 
Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.6 [C:\Program     Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0_old [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4_old [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

On my local docker:

```
Host (useful for support):
Version: 2.1.6
Commit:  3f4f8eebd8

.NET Core SDKs installed:
No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Are you specifying the version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in the project file?

Comment: @DavidG yes, I have: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.6" />

Interesting enough, if I just create a new project, and add that nuget-package, but not using any references directly in the code, the same error appears.

I can note that I added the DockerFile/Compose via visual studio add-> "Container Orchestrator support".

Comment: You shouldn't be specifying the version for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in .NET Core 2.1, remove that completely. I assume you have upgrade from v2.0 to v2.1? See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1#update-the-project-file-to-use-21-versions) doc for info.

Comment: @DavidG ok, I created a completely new project, and just added the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, and it gives the same error. I updated my question including the versions. *edit* Checked the doc, I can't understand any more things I would need to do with a new project, the others feels more when you upgrade from an old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently there was an issue if the project was created as a console application and use the nuget Microsoft.aspnetcore.app. I re-created the project but as a Web application and then it worked. Maybe it's obvious because it's a "web-nuget", but it didn't cross my mind.

I should note that I got some issues with the docker image, and had to pull the dotnet docker-image again with specific version.

```
docker pull microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
```

It wouldn't load/start with the correct dotnet version.